# Magento 2.2 search does not find 2 number skus - like 21, 46, 54 etc

Tags: magento2, magento2.2

I am having the hardest time with this. We have skus that are of the form NN or NN-NN where N is a number below 10. We also have skus that are CC-CCCC where C is a character form a-z.
I have set the minimum word length in search to 2, and also set the word length for mysql. 
BUT - I still cannot get the front end search to work for searches like 21, 46, 46-54 etc.
Has anyone else encountered this problem? Are there any settings else where? Is there a section of code I can modify?
Thanks very much
Sam

Comment: Magento version? I would recommend checking github, this sounds like a bug. I vaguely remember a bug concerning, oddly enough, a specific sku or ID having issues but can't quite remember...